# Do session variables still exist after a purchase through Stripe's site?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, session-variables

I'm writing a website where the user logs in through conventional means. The login creates session variables so the site knows if and who is logged in.

There are products on the site that sell through Stripe. For ease I'm using Stripe's payment links. So you click a link on my site, it then visits Stripe's site to enter card details, then back to mine on checkout success.

My question is this: Are the session variables guaranteed to stay through that diversion so the user is still logged in when their payment is successful and they've been to Stripe and back or should I pass the customer id, etc. through the payment process and recreate all the session variables again once they arrive on the success page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

The important thing to remember is that HTTP is *completely stateless* - every request is completely independent of any previous ones. As far as the web server is concerned, *every time the user loads a new page* that's equivalent to them "going away and coming back". Sessions work by telling the browser to associate a cookie with a particular domain, and then using that cookie to recognise that two requests came from the same user. As long as that cookie is still there, it doesn't matter if the user has visited another site in between, or opened a new browser window, or whatever.

However, it's a good idea to plan for what will happen if the cookie *isn't* there when they come back: customers tend to get very annoyed if you take the payment but don't complete the order. Another scenario to consider is that the payment completes but for whatever reason the user doesn't get redirected back at the end of the payment process (I've had this happen with malfunctioning security software on the user's PC, for instance).

A good approach if you can manage it is therefore to create a "pending" order in your system, with all the details of who was logged in and what they were trying to buy. Then you have a single ID you can pass through Stripe and receive for a successful payment. If the session disappears, you still know which order to confirm; and if orders get stuck in "pending" status for a long time, you can check in Stripe if a payment was actually made, and sort the order out manually.

Comment: That's an excellent idea. I mean you've just added another day onto my work time, but I can't fault your logic. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.